# How TO: obtain the list of names from the phonebook to be used in a list view?

Tags: android, android-widget

This might be a really simple answer but I cant seem to come up with an answer for it, I'm aiming for android 2.1.

Any help would be great :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this within your Activity or other application component:

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor cur = cr.query(People.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                String name = formatName(cur.getString(cur
                                .getColumnIndex(People.DISPLAY_NAME)));
                // Do something with name.
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 First you have to add `ListView` in your layout file   

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now use this code in your `Activity` :

```
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(People.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    startManagingCursor(c);

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
            c, 
            new String[] {People.NAME} ,
            new int[] {android.R.id.text1}); 
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```